# Unable to load script from assets 'index.android.bundle' followed by FATAL EXCEPTION: mqt_native_modules

Tags: android, exception, react-native, runtimeexception

I am very new to **React-Native**, developing my first React-native App. Previously it was working fine but then i installed a library then i faced the below error

**java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to load script from assets 'index.android.bundle'. Make sure your bundle is packaged correctly or you're running a packager server.** .

Then i found [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44476757/7134908)  for the same issue. so i run command

**react-native bundle --platform android --dev false --entry-file App.js --bundle-output android/app/src/main/assets/index.android.bundle --assets-dest android/app/src/main/res**

It resolve the first error but then i face second(below) error.

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: mqt_native_modules
    Process: com.nickinaturizer, PID: 18969
                                                                        com.facebook.react.common.JavascriptException: Module AppRegistry is not a registered callable module (calling runApplication), stack:
                                                                        value@23:3036
                                                                        <unknown>@23:911
                                                                        value@23:2606
                                                                        value@23:883
                                                                        at com.facebook.react.modules.core.ExceptionsManagerModule.showOrThrowError(ExceptionsManagerModule.java:56)
    at com.facebook.react.modules.core.ExceptionsManagerModule.reportFatalException(ExceptionsManagerModule.java:40)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.facebook.react.bridge.JavaMethodWrapper.invoke(JavaMethodWrapper.java:374)
    at com.facebook.react.bridge.JavaModuleWrapper.invoke(JavaModuleWrapper.java:162)
    at com.facebook.react.bridge.queue.NativeRunnable.run(Native Method)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
    at com.facebook.react.bridge.queue.MessageQueueThreadHandler.dispatchMessage(MessageQueueThreadHandler.java:31)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
    at com.facebook.react.bridge.queue.MessageQueueThreadImpl$3.run(MessageQueueThreadImpl.java:194)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
```

**So i am having two questions regarding these error.**

**1.** What is the use of `index.android.bundle` file when my project is running fine before.

**2.** Is there any quick fix for those both error.

I am using react-native version: 0.51.0

Comment: Do you run `adb reverse tcp:8081 tcp:8081` on cmd before running the app?

Comment: @Levon Yes tried, but facing the same(second) issue