# React Native app is showing some errors while initiating first app

Tags: android, react-native, terminal

I am new to **react native**. I followed all the steps guided by *Facebook react-native website*. But i am facing these issues while initiating me *app*.Please help me how can i solve this issue. It is showing some warnings while initiating my first *app*.

Error is:

```
npm WARN @babel/plugin-transform-parameters@7.0.0-beta.40 requires a peer of @babel/core@7.0.0-beta.40 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN @babel/plugin-transform-spread@7.0.0-beta.40 requires a peer of @babel/core@7.0.0-beta.40 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN @babel/plugin-transform-for-of@7.0.0-beta.40 requires a peer of @babel/core@7.0.0-beta.40 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN @babel/plugin-transform-computed-properties@7.0.0-beta.40 requires a peer of @babel/core@7.0.0-beta.40 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN @babel/plugin-transform-regenerator@7.0.0-beta.40 requires a peer of @babel/core@7.0.0-beta.40 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN @babel/plugin-transform-shorthand-properties@7.0.0-beta.40 requires a peer of @babel/core@7.0.0-beta.40 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN @babel/plugin-transform-template-literals@7.0.0-beta.40 requires a peer of @babel/core@7.0.0-beta.40 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN @babel/plugin-syntax-class-properties@7.0.0-beta.40 requires a peer of @babel/core@7.0.0-beta.40 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN @babel/plugin-syntax-object-rest-spread@7.0.0-beta.40 requires a peer of @babel/core@7.0.0-beta.40 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN @babel/plugin-syntax-flow@7.0.0-beta.40 requires a peer of @babel/core@7.0.0-beta.40 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN @babel/plugin-syntax-jsx@7.0.0-beta.40 requires a peer of @babel/core@7.0.0-beta.40 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN eslint-plugin-react-native@3.2.1 requires a peer of eslint@^3.17.0 || ^4.0.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN @babel/plugin-transform-sticky-regex@7.0.0-beta.40 requires a peer of @babel/core@7.0.0-beta.40 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN @babel/plugin-transform-unicode-regex@7.0.0-beta.40 requires a peer of @babel/core@7.0.0-beta.40 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@1.2.0 (node_modules\fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@1.2.0: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"win32","arch":"x64"})
```

Answer (score 4):

You can run the following command: 
npm install @babel/core@7.0.0-beta.40 eslint@^3.17.0 || ^4.0.0

If you are missing any other peers, you can run npm install followed by the missing peer dependencies.

Add a space between each peer.

References:
npm install complains about peer deps. Github, Inc.
https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/5746 (accessed April 22, 2018).

Comment: i am also getting red screen when my application launched. Why it is happening?? is it happening Due to absence of peer dependencies??

Comment: @Haseeb  What does the error message on the screen?

Comment: Completely red screen with this Error:

Comment: Unable to load script from assets 'index.android.bundle'. Make sure your bundle is packaged correctly or you are running a packager server.

Comment: how to add this command?? Should i run my terminal 'run as administrator' or not??

Comment: If you mean the one in my answer, you only need to run the command in my answer.  As for the index.android.bundle problem, try this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/44476757/8121551.  I can't replicate the error so I don't know if it will work.