# React-Native Can't run correctly

Tags: android, react-native

I have installed react-native and setup it in my pc when I ran it on android it always error.
 Anyone can help me ? I was looking for on youtube and other forum for 1 night but the result is nihil.
this is the screenshot of the error
https://i.stack.imgur.com/vHqjZ.jpg

Comment: Restart the terminal running the packager, or just re-run the Android run command.

Comment: thanks for answer but still that screenshoot is shown.

Comment: In general when I see that message restarting everything resolves it. When it doesn't there's usually an error in the same terminal, or an error in Android Studio that needs to be resolved.

Comment: Please share in detail about the steps you followed to install react native

Comment: check this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/44476757/6359528

Answer (score 0):

Try

`npm i`

`rm ./node_modules/react-native/local-cli/core/**fixtures**/files/package.json`

`react-native bundle --platform android --dev false --entry-file index.js --bundle-output android/app/src/main/assets/index.android.bundle --assets-dest android/app/src/main/res && react-native run-android`

Make sure the server is on. If you still get the same problem go to dev settings (by shaking your device) and set debug IP address and port to

`192.xxx.xxx.xxx:_port_numer` and reload it

Answer (score 0):

try to eliminate the basic node processes that may have remained active:

```
ps aux | grep node
sudo kill {PID of process}
```

usually I kill the "starter"