# Setting up First Project in React Native

Tags: android, react-native, device, setup-project

Anybody has any idea of how to set up the react native code. I am new to react native and when I am setting up the code following the guide from the net, it is running in android emulator but giving me an error of

> "Unable to load script from assets 'index.android.bundle'. Make sure your bundle is packaged correctly or you're running a packager server." when running on a real device.

I have followed everything which is available on net and stack overflow but did not avail any success. Please Help me regarding this by inboxing me all the details regarding this.

Comment: Check this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/44476757/5167909

Comment: Thanks a lot for this link. But I have already used this but no success.

Comment: You want https://stackoverflow.com/a/46250725/295675 the issue is that it can't find your server. If it's connected to your comp by USB, you'll need adb reverse to ensure that it can connect to the server.

Comment: I have used 
D:\ReactNativeWorkspace\FirstProject>mkdir android/app/src/main/assets like this but its showing :
The syntax of the command is incorrect.
Similarly I have used 
D:\ReactNativeWorkspace\FirstProject>adb reverse tcp:8081 tcp:8081
but it showing me
'adb' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

Answer (score 0):

Delete Project from emulator and again start Packager.

Comment: Its running on emulator but giving this error when I am running the above on real device.