# unable to load script from assets 'index.android.bundle'.- React Native

Tags: android

I have run a React Native project on Windows by using `react-native run-android` command. I got the following error in the emulator:

> Unable to load script from assets 'index.android.bundle' .Make sure your bundle is packaged correctly or you are running a package server.

[image]

I tried these links but not work with me.

[Unable to load script from assets index.android.bundle on windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44446523/unable-to-load-script-from-assets-index-android-bundle-on-windows).

Comment: check this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/55511740/10139109

Comment: I was facing the same issue and it solves my problem: https://queception.com/question.php?question=10

Comment: please check this link, i hope can help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55441230/unable-to-load-script-make-sure-you-are-either-running-a-metro-server-or-that-yo

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error in the same context, and it was simply because the app launched before the development server finished to bundle up the files. Make sure you wait untill the node development server displays:

`Loading dependency graph, done`

and hit reload on the app.

Answer (score 0):

Go to your project folder android/app/src/main/assets

Delete index.android.bundle and index.android.bundle.meta

If assets directory not there create new one.

Go to root project > cd android

> ./gradlew/clean

In root folder run following command if there was index.js file

> react-native bundle --platform android --dev false --entry-file index.js --bundle-output android/app/src/main/assets/index.android.bundle --assets-dest android/app/src/main/res

If there are two files index.android.js and index.ios.js then run

> react-native bundle --platform android --dev false --entry-file index.android.js --bundle-output android/app/src/main/assets/index.android.bundle --assets-dest android/app/src/main/res

Above two are single line commands.