# Unable to load script. Make sure you're either running a Metro server (run 'react-native start') or that your bundle 'index.android.bundle'

Tags: react-native

Running my project in android studio I get that error, I just installed everything and I followed everything step by step, I'm using `genymotion` as an emulator, and use `react-native start` from the root, check port 8081, disable instant run, everything which is the following link

[Unable to load script.Make sure you are either running a Metro server or that your bundle 'index.android.bundle' is packaged correctly for release](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55441230/unable-to-load-script-make-sure-you-are-either-running-a-metro-server-or-that-yo)

Comment: I had the same issue , this link removed my problem : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55441230/unable-to-load-script-make-sure-you-are-either-running-a-metro-server-or-that-yo/59022921#59022921

Answer (score 13):

First of all make sure you have started the `bundler` using this command in root directory:

```
npm start
```

or

```
react-native start
```

**If doesn't work** add *assets* folder manually in the following directory

```
android/app/src/main/{assets}
```

After that rename `index.android.js` to `index.js` then use the following command:

```
react-native bundle --platform android --dev false --entry-file index.js --bundle-output android/app/src/main/assets/index.android.bundle --assets-dest android/app/src/main/res
```

Now you can create your `apk`:

```
react-native run-android
```

Comment: this lik can be helpfull : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55441230/unable-to-load-script-make-sure-you-are-either-running-a-metro-server-or-that-yo/59022921#59022921

Answer (score 7):

"react-native": "0.64.1",

I've resolved this problem with changing `bundleInDebug: true,` in `project.ext.react` in `android > app > build.gradle`.

```
project.ext.react = [
bundleInDebug: true,
enableHermes: ***,  
]
```

Comment: That's it. But is it the correct way of resolving this issue? I mean the name 'bundleInDebug' seems to be related to the debugging mode!

Answer (score 4):

For anyone that the above didn't help, I run:

```
adb devices
```

This should give you an output similar to this:

```
List of devices attached
98XAY181GQ  device
```

The numbers/letters will be different for you. Then run the following command, replacing the word "device" with the string of numbers/letters that was printed out with the previous command:

```
adb -s device reverse tcp:8081 tcp:8081
```

Then I re-run the emulator in Android studio and it works. Hope this helps someone!

Comment: This applies to both emulators and USB connected devices. Sometimes it just doesn't work without doing this... Shortcut if you only have a single device is `adb reverse tcp:8081 tcp:8081`.

Answer (score 2):

I resolved this issue as below

- Changed the directory to <app_name>
- run command `react-native start`
- Open Another tab in terminal
- run command `react-native run-android`

Whenever we save the files, it will be automatically update in device. No need to call run app again and again.

I am using a physical device for running the app.

Answer (score 2):

This usually happens in Android. 
To correct this, you have to change the bundle Location.

By default: it's set to localhost:8081.

**For Android, you need to update to your local IP address appended with port: *ip-address*:8081.** like xxx.xxx.x.x:8081

in Mac, you can find your Local IP address under System Preference>Network.
This worked for me!

Answer (score 2):

I was having this issue with react-native-cli: 2.0.1  and react-native: 0.62.2

Run   `npm start` in one terminal and in another terminal Run `react-native run-android`

Answer (score 1):

I also faced this problem. But couldn't find a best solution.

But after I turning off the **airplane mode** in the android emulator and **turn on wifi**, the app runs without an error.

Answer (score 0):

In my case , I was making a mistake in build.gradle file.
you can change your 
`targetSdkVersion from 28 to 27,
minSdkVersion to 21.`
then you can clean your gradlew and then run react-native run-android.

Answer (score 0):

You can check your Metro **server is on or not**..?

do the following command in your cmd path on your server

open two **cmd** window do **2nd** point and **3rd** point another **cmd** window

1. check you localhost 8080 is running your **browser** chrome

**like**: localhost:8080

//----- then do this in your cmd path

2. **D:para\Android\testing>react-native start --port=8081**
3. **D:para\Android\testing>react-native run-android --no-jetifier**

That's it... check your mobile or emulator now show welcome to react...

Thank you.