# unable to load script. make sure you're either running a metro server in React-Native

Tags: react-native

I have tried clearing the cache and running in a different port and react-native start is also giving an error.

React-Native Version - 0.59.9
OS - Windows 10
[screensot of the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DP5sH.png)
running react-native start  also doesn't work

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Unable to load script.Make sure you are either running a Metro server or that your bundle 'index.android.bundle' is packaged correctly for release](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55441230/unable-to-load-script-make-sure-you-are-either-running-a-metro-server-or-that-yo)

Comment: I have tried all the solutions in that as well. none of it worked. I have updated my node as well