# react-native hellow world app - working in emulator but not in physical device

Tags: android, react-native

I'm new to React-native and i create my first hello world program. In android studio emulator it works fine.
Emulator shows

I used following commands

```
react-native start
react-native run-android
```

[image]

But when i get the app-debug.apk file from output folder and install in my physical mobile phone it gives following error. (This is a screenshot)

[image]

Have i done wrong somewhere?

Thank you

Comment: The problem is that app can not connect to development server. If you'd like to install apk file to your physical devices, you have to build in release mode. Or you should set `Debug server host & port` to your machine.

Answer (score 1):

https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/running-on-device 
follow these steps, don't copy an apk file.

Answer (score 0):

Add this line in package.json

```
script:{
--
 "android-dev": "adb reverse tcp:8081 tcp:8081 && react-native run-android"
}
```

and run this command :

```
adb reverse tcp:8081 tcp:8081 
react-native run-android
```

Answer (score 0):

i suggest to use this steps to run your apk from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56399952/10999528)  answer

These steps really help me:

Step 1: Create a directory in android/app/src/main/assets

Linux command: `mkdir android/app/src/main/assets`

Step 2: Rename `index.android.js` (in root directory) to `index.js` (Maybe there is an `index.js` file in which case you do not need to rename it) then run the following command:

`react-native bundle --platform android --dev false --entry-file index.js --bundle-output android/app/src/main/assets/index.android.bundle --assets-dest android/app/src/main/res`

Step 3: Build your APK: `react-native run-android`