# Unable to Load script: "Make sure you're either Running a Metro Server ( run 'react-native start')" issue

Tags: android, reactjs, react-native, android-emulator

[Screenshot from Emulator](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O3p1p.png)

We have tried a few things such as following the steps provided and shared by other Devs in the other channels, as well as updating the package. We're not Mobile Developers and have been asking around to unblock this for us. Please, help share a few tricks and things that we may have missed before. I am writing this on behalf of the team.

Thanks again

Comment: How did you run the app? Did you try to run `react-native start` as it says in the error?

Comment: You're running a debug build. So, you need to start the server and connect it to the mobile device.

Comment: I solved it by following the answer by Mahmonir in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63053905/unable-to-load-script-make-sure-you-are-either-running-a-metro-server-or-that-y