# React native - Unable to load script in android emulator

Tags: android, react-native, metro-bundler

I ejected an expo project and tried running `npm start` and `npx react-native run-android`. The bundler runs and shows this

> To reload the app press "r"

> To open developer menu press "d"

The app is installed in the emulator, but shows the following error.

> [unable to load script](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H2Flr.png). make sure you're either running a metro
> server (run 'react-native start') or that your bundle
> 'index.android.bundle' is packaged correctly for release.

The emulator is able to reach the host machine IP address in the browser.

I tried the following solutions.

- [Run npm start or react-native start in the root directory of your project before react-native run-android](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55442281)
- [android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56808180)
- [Changing port](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55450873)

Nothing helped me. What could be the issue?