# TypeError: Network request failed. sourceURL: 'index.android.bundle'

Tags: react-native

The `fetch` in the React Native 0.62.3 app starts to go nowhere without any code change. After launching another RN 0.63.2 app and coming back to this one, the `npx react-native run-android` starts to lose connection to the backend server. The error is:

```
[12:32:26] I | ReactNativeJS ▶︎ 'Error in retrieving storage access info: ', { [TypeError: Network request failed] line: 113, column: 8117, sourceURL: 'index.android.bundle' }
```

Before that, there was error of "Unable to load script" as below:

[image]

Run following command to fix from a [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55441230/unable-to-load-script-make-sure-you-are-either-running-a-metro-server-or-that-yo):

```
react-native bundle --platform android --dev false --entry-file index.js --bundle-output android/app/src/main/assets/index.android.bundle --assets-dest android/app/src/main/res
```

Then this error about network connection appears. How to fix this error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to the root of your application,

Run this command separately, `npm start --reset-cache`

Comment: same problem remains after `npm start --reset-cache`.

Comment: Try these,
1. Running packager on port react-native start --port 8086 --reset-cache
2. Run react-native run-android --port 8086 in other terminal
After error screen, try Ctrl + M for android and, iOS Command + D.
3.Click Dev Settings button at the bottom.
Click Debug server host & port for device button.
Type localhost:8086 and click OK button.
Again run react-native run-android --port 8086

Comment: If it still doesnt work. Try npm audit fix

Comment: I can only carry out first 2 steps, but without error. What is the purpose of the command? Many thanks.

Comment: I decided to cold reboot the system and that's all I did. Now the app is back to normal. I don't know why and there is no explanation of how reboot solves the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Probably the app wasn't built properly.

Step 1: Go to the root of the project in the terminal and run the below command:

`react-native bundle --platform android --dev false --entry-file index.js --bundle-output android/app/src/main/assets/index.android.bundle --assets-dest android/app/src/main/res`

Step 2: Go to android directory: cd android

Step 3: Now in this android folder, run this command

`./gradlew assembleDebug`