# Getting error when trying to execute react native app on Windows

Tags: android, reactjs, react-native, native

I am getting error when I'm trying to execute the react-native app.

1. I have created a sample app using [tutorial link](http://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/getting-started.html).
2. After I have created an AwesomeProject as mentioned in the document,
3. I have started the server using "npm install" && "npm start"
4. Run the app using "react-native run-android"
5. I am getting the below issue.
   [image]

Please could anyone help me to execute this.

Comment: Have a look here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44446523/unable-to-load-script-from-assets-index-android-bundle-on-windows

Comment: Thank you, it's resolved with this.