# react native app works, but both APK and --variant=release crash repeatedly upon loading

Tags: android, android-studio, react-native, apk, bundler

After running logcat.  I discovered the follow error exception:

```
AndroidRuntime: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to load script from assets 'index.android.bundle'. Make sure your bundle is packaged correctly or you're running a packager server.
```

Doesn't creating an apk/running the variant release version automatically include the bundler?  How do I rebuild and verify that the bundler has been included in the apk/variant release?

I tried adding `bundleAssetName: "index.android.bundle",`
to

```
project.ext.react = [
    entryFile: "index.js",
    bundleAssetName: "index.android.bundle",
]
```

I still got the same issue(repeatedly crashing).  I did a search for "exception" and found this error:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Requested window android.os.BinderProxy@b60a260 does not exist
```

Comment: try [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44446523/unable-to-load-script-from-assets-index-android-bundle-on-windows)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to make sure the bundler is included in the apk, this was needed

```
react-native bundle --platform android --dev false --entry-file index.js --bundle-output android/app/src/main/assets/index.android.bundle --assets-dest android/app/src/main/res
```

Shamelessly taken from this [post.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44446523/unable-to-load-script-from-assets-index-android-bundle-on-windows)