# Module HMRClient is not a registered callable module (calling enable) in Linux

Tags: reactjs, react-native

[image]

First When I created the app with react-native init project1 .
I was getting an error as below

**Unable to load script from assets index.android.bundle on windows**

Later I solved this issue by running following commands Stackoverflow [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44446523/unable-to-load-script-from-assets-index-android-bundle-on-windows)

mkdir android/app/src/main/assets

react-native bundle --platform android --dev false --entry-file index.js --bundle-output android/app/src/main/assets/index.android.bundle --assets-dest android/app/src/main/res

react-native run-android

But later I am getting an error like this and not able to solve, Module **HMRClient is not a registered callable module (calling enable)**

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is the common occurred problem, but there will not be some problem in bundling the app, Just follow some common steps and it worked for me.
Delete node_module folder and install npm

```
rm -rf node_modules && npm install

cd android && ./gradlew clean
```

then `cd .. && react-native run-android`

Comment: I was Deleting Node Modules and Trying to run but still getting the same error, after running cd android && ./gradlew clean
Now Its solved.  Thank you,

Comment: not working for me on real android device. It shows "Hot loading" at the bottom during a change, but nothing updates. RN 0.60.4 here.

Comment: And also we need to disable hot reloading and of course when we clean build it hot reload will be disabled. but unfortunately not in iOS

Answer (score 3):

If you're developing a native module and your `npm link`'d folder contains a `node_modules` directory, this can also produce the error.

To correct for this case, you can delete the `node_modules` directory, re-install your project in the linked folder and use `react-native start --reset-cache`.

Answer (score 2):

Disable hot reloading, it will work fine

Comment: It's literally super hard to code an app WITHOUT hot reloading. That shouldn't be a possible fix in anyone's mind.

Comment: This is one of the correct truth that hot reloading has to be disabled. it worked after clean build.

Answer (score 1):

This issue occurs if we enabled the production mode from dev setting by unchecking "JS Dev Mode" and then try to enable the hot reload.
Enable JS Dev Mode again will work.