# App crashes on startup, works fine in debug mode

Tags: react-native, react-native-firebase

I have added rnfirebase to my project recently for fcm, I have setup everything as per the documentation and I can even see notifications coming through to my app in emulator(debug mode). But app crashes only in release mode. Says 'Unfortunately app has stopped'. build has no errors, I have even checked android studio and there are no errors there as well.

Can someone help me debug the issue? Thanks

My logcat output is below

```
12-06 15:15:57.041 9500-9500/? I/art: Not late-enabling -Xcheck:jni (already on)
12-06 15:15:57.116 9500-9500/com.demoparentapp D/SoLoader: init start
    adding system library source: /vendor/lib
    adding system library source: /system/lib
12-06 15:15:57.117 9500-9500/com.demoparentapp D/SoLoader: adding application source: com.facebook.soloader.DirectorySoSource[root = /data/app/com.demoparentapp-1/lib/x86 flags = 0]
12-06 15:15:57.132 9500-9500/com.demoparentapp D/SoLoader: adding backup  source: com.facebook.soloader.ApkSoSource[root = /data/data/com.demoparentapp/lib-main flags = 1]
12-06 15:15:57.133 9500-9500/com.demoparentapp D/SoLoader: Preparing SO source: com.facebook.soloader.DirectorySoSource[root = /system/lib flags = 2]
    Preparing SO source: com.facebook.soloader.DirectorySoSource[root = /system/vendor/lib flags = 2]
12-06 15:15:57.134 9500-9500/com.demoparentapp D/SoLoader: Preparing SO source: com.facebook.soloader.DirectorySoSource[root = /data/app/com.demoparentapp-1/lib/x86 flags = 0]
    Preparing SO source: com.facebook.soloader.ApkSoSource[root = /data/data/com.demoparentapp/lib-main flags = 1]
12-06 15:15:57.134 9500-9500/com.demoparentapp V/fb-UnpackingSoSource: locked dso store /data/user/0/com.demoparentapp/lib-main
12-06 15:15:57.138 9500-9500/com.demoparentapp I/fb-UnpackingSoSource: dso store is up-to-date: /data/user/0/com.demoparentapp/lib-main
12-06 15:15:57.138 9500-9500/com.demoparentapp V/fb-UnpackingSoSource: releasing dso store lock for /data/user/0/com.demoparentapp/lib-main
12-06 15:15:57.141 9500-9500/com.demoparentapp D/SoLoader: init finish: 4 SO sources prepared
    init exiting
12-06 15:15:57.189 9500-9500/com.demoparentapp D/ReactNative: ReactInstanceManager.ctor()
12-06 15:15:57.189 9500-9500/com.demoparentapp D/SoLoader: init exiting
12-06 15:15:57.250 9500-9500/com.demoparentapp D/ReactNative: ReactInstanceManager.createReactContextInBackground()
12-06 15:15:57.253 9500-9500/com.demoparentapp D/ReactNative: ReactInstanceManager.recreateReactContextInBackgroundInner()
12-06 15:15:57.255 9500-9500/com.demoparentapp D/ReactNative: ReactInstanceManager.onJSBundleLoadedFromServer()
12-06 15:15:57.256 9500-9500/com.demoparentapp D/ReactNative: ReactInstanceManager.recreateReactContextInBackground()
12-06 15:15:57.257 9500-9500/com.demoparentapp D/ReactNative: ReactInstanceManager.runCreateReactContextOnNewThread()
12-06 15:15:57.267 9500-9516/com.demoparentapp D/SoLoader: About to load: libreactnativejni.so
12-06 15:15:57.268 9500-9516/com.demoparentapp D/SoLoader: libreactnativejni.so not found on /data/data/com.demoparentapp/lib-main
12-06 15:15:57.269 9500-9516/com.demoparentapp D/SoLoader: libreactnativejni.so found on /data/app/com.demoparentapp-1/lib/x86
    Not resolving dependencies for libreactnativejni.so
12-06 15:15:57.346 9500-9517/com.demoparentapp W/unknown:InspectorPackagerConnection: Couldn't connect to packager, will silently retry
12-06 15:15:57.350 9500-9519/com.demoparentapp D/OpenGLRenderer: Use EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR_PRESERVED: true
12-06 15:15:57.394 9500-9500/com.demoparentapp W/unknown:ReactNative: Packager connection already open, nooping.
12-06 15:15:57.420 9500-9516/com.demoparentapp D/SoLoader: Loaded: libreactnativejni.so
    About to load: libfb.so
    libfb.so not found on /data/data/com.demoparentapp/lib-main
12-06 15:15:57.421 9500-9516/com.demoparentapp D/SoLoader: libfb.so found on /data/app/com.demoparentapp-1/lib/x86
    Not resolving dependencies for libfb.so
12-06 15:15:57.424 9500-9516/com.demoparentapp D/SoLoader: About to load: libfb.so
    libfb.so not found on /data/data/com.demoparentapp/lib-main
    libfb.so found on /data/app/com.demoparentapp-1/lib/x86
    Not resolving dependencies for libfb.so
12-06 15:15:57.425 9500-9516/com.demoparentapp I/art: Thread[12,tid=9516,Native,Thread*=0xec47ac00,peer=0x12d5f400,"Thread-110"] recursive attempt to load library "/data/app/com.demoparentapp-1/lib/x86/libfb.so"
12-06 15:15:57.425 9500-9516/com.demoparentapp D/SoLoader: Loaded: libfb.so
    Loaded: libfb.so
12-06 15:15:57.431 9500-9516/com.demoparentapp D/ReactNative: ReactInstanceManager.createReactContext()
12-06 15:15:57.440 9500-9516/com.demoparentapp W/unknown:ViewManagerPropertyUpdater: Could not find generated setter for class com.facebook.react.views.art.ARTGroupViewManager
12-06 15:15:57.441 9500-9516/com.demoparentapp W/unknown:ViewManagerPropertyUpdater: Could not find generated setter for class com.facebook.react.views.art.ARTGroupShadowNode
12-06 15:15:57.442 9500-9516/com.demoparentapp W/unknown:ViewManagerPropertyUpdater: Could not find generated setter for class com.facebook.react.views.art.ARTShapeViewManager
12-06 15:15:57.443 9500-9516/com.demoparentapp W/unknown:ViewManagerPropertyUpdater: Could not find generated setter for class com.facebook.react.views.art.ARTShapeShadowNode
12-06 15:15:57.444 9500-9516/com.demoparentapp W/unknown:ViewManagerPropertyUpdater: Could not find generated setter for class com.facebook.react.views.art.ARTTextViewManager
12-06 15:15:57.445 9500-9516/com.demoparentapp W/unknown:ViewManagerPropertyUpdater: Could not find generated setter for class com.facebook.react.views.art.ARTTextShadowNode
12-06 15:15:57.446 9500-9516/com.demoparentapp W/unknown:ViewManagerPropertyUpdater: Could not find generated setter for class com.facebook.react.views.checkbox.ReactCheckBoxManager
12-06 15:15:57.450 9500-9516/com.demoparentapp W/unknown:ViewManagerPropertyUpdater: Could not find generated setter for class com.facebook.react.uimanager.LayoutShadowNode
12-06 15:15:57.453 9500-9516/com.demoparentapp W/unknown:ViewManagerPropertyUpdater: Could not find generated setter for class com.facebook.react.views.picker.ReactDialogPickerManager
12-06 15:15:57.454 9500-9516/com.demoparentapp W/unknown:ViewManagerPropertyUpdater: Could not find generated setter for class com.facebook.react.views.drawer.ReactDrawerLayoutManager
12-06 15:15:57.456 9500-9516/com.demoparentapp W/unknown:ViewManagerPropertyUpdater: Could not find generated setter for class com.facebook.react.views.picker.ReactDropdownPickerManager
    Could not find generated setter for class com.facebook.react.views.scroll.ReactHorizontalScrollViewManager
12-06 15:15:57.458 9500-9516/com.demoparentapp W/unknown:ViewManagerPropertyUpdater: Could not find generated setter for class com.facebook.react.views.scroll.ReactHorizontalScrollContainerViewManager
    Could not find generated setter for class com.facebook.react.views.progressbar.ReactProgressBarViewManager
12-06 15:15:57.459 9500-9516/com.demoparentapp W/unknown:ViewManagerPropertyUpdater: Could not find generated setter for class com.facebook.react.views.progressbar.ProgressBarShadowNode
12-06 15:15:57.462 9500-9516/com.demoparentapp W/unknown:ViewManagerPropertyUpdater: Could not find generated setter for class com.facebook.react.views.scroll.ReactScrollViewManager
12-06 15:15:57.465 9500-9516/com.demoparentapp W/unknown:ViewManagerPropertyUpdater: Could not find generated setter for class com.facebook.react.views.slider.ReactSliderManager
12-06 15:15:57.466 9500-9516/com.demoparentapp W/unknown:ViewManagerPropertyUpdater: Could not find generated setter for class com.facebook.react.views.slider.ReactSliderManager$ReactSliderShadowNode
    Could not find generated setter for class com.facebook.react.views.switchview.ReactSwitchManager
12-06 15:15:57.470 9500-9516/com.demoparentapp W/unknown:ViewManagerPropertyUpdater: Could not find generated setter for class com.facebook.react.views.switchview.ReactSwitchManager$ReactSwitchShadowNode
    Could not find generated setter for class com.facebook.react.views.toolbar.ReactToolbarManager
12-06 15:15:57.481 9500-9516/com.demoparentapp W/unknown:ViewManagerPropertyUpdater: Could not find generated setter for class com.facebook.react.views.webview.ReactWebViewManager
12-06 15:15:57.490 9500-9516/com.demoparentapp W/unknown:ViewManagerPropertyUpdater: Could not find generated setter for class com.facebook.react.views.swiperefresh.SwipeRefreshLayoutManager
12-06 15:15:57.492 9500-9516/com.demoparentapp W/unknown:ViewManagerPropertyUpdater: Could not find generated setter for class com.facebook.react.views.art.ARTSurfaceViewManager
    Could not find generated setter for class com.facebook.react.views.art.ARTSurfaceViewShadowNode
    Could not find generated setter for class com.facebook.react.views.text.frescosupport.FrescoBasedReactTextInlineImageViewManager
12-06 15:15:57.493 9500-9516/com.demoparentapp W/unknown:ViewManagerPropertyUpdater: Could not find generated setter for class com.facebook.react.views.text.frescosupport.FrescoBasedReactTextInlineImageShadowNode
12-06 15:15:57.494 9500-9516/com.demoparentapp W/unknown:ViewManagerPropertyUpdater: Could not find generated setter for class com.facebook.react.views.image.ReactImageManager
12-06 15:15:57.500 9500-9516/com.demoparentapp W/unknown:ViewManagerPropertyUpdater: Could not find generated setter for class com.facebook.react.views.modal.ReactModalHostManager
12-06 15:15:57.501 9500-9516/com.demoparentapp W/unknown:ViewManagerPropertyUpdater: Could not find generated setter for class com.facebook.react.views.modal.ModalHostShadowNode
12-06 15:15:57.502 9500-9516/com.demoparentapp W/unknown:ViewManagerPropertyUpdater: Could not find generated setter for class com.facebook.react.views.text.ReactRawTextManager
    Could not find generated setter for class com.facebook.react.views.text.ReactRawTextShadowNode
12-06 15:15:57.503 9500-9516/com.demoparentapp W/unknown:ViewManagerPropertyUpdater: Could not find generated setter for class com.facebook.react.views.textinput.ReactTextInputManager
12-06 15:15:57.506 9500-9516/com.demoparentapp W/unknown:ViewManagerPropertyUpdater: Could not find generated setter for class com.facebook.react.views.textinput.ReactTextInputShadowNode
12-06 15:15:57.507 9500-9516/com.demoparentapp W/unknown:ViewManagerPropertyUpdater: Could not find generated setter for class com.facebook.react.views.text.ReactTextViewManager
    Could not find generated setter for class com.facebook.react.views.text.ReactTextShadowNode
    Could not find generated setter for class com.facebook.react.views.view.ReactViewManager
12-06 15:15:57.508 9500-9519/com.demoparentapp I/OpenGLRenderer: Initialized EGL, version 1.4
12-06 15:15:57.508 9500-9519/com.demoparentapp W/OpenGLRenderer: Failed to choose config with EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR_PRESERVED, retrying without...
12-06 15:15:57.508 9500-9516/com.demoparentapp W/unknown:ViewManagerPropertyUpdater: Could not find generated setter for class com.facebook.react.views.viewpager.ReactViewPagerManager
12-06 15:15:57.509 9500-9516/com.demoparentapp W/unknown:ViewManagerPropertyUpdater: Could not find generated setter for class com.facebook.react.views.text.ReactVirtualTextViewManager
12-06 15:15:57.510 9500-9516/com.demoparentapp W/unknown:ViewManagerPropertyUpdater: Could not find generated setter for class com.facebook.react.views.text.ReactVirtualTextShadowNode
12-06 15:15:57.511 9500-9519/com.demoparentapp D/EGL_emulation: eglCreateContext: 0xefff9e20: maj 3 min 0 rcv 3
12-06 15:15:57.515 9500-9519/com.demoparentapp D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0xefff9e20: ver 3 0 (tinfo 0xe9e820d0)
12-06 15:15:57.518 9500-9519/com.demoparentapp E/eglCodecCommon: glUtilsParamSize: unknow param 0x00008cdf
    glUtilsParamSize: unknow param 0x00008824
12-06 15:15:57.535 9500-9516/com.demoparentapp D/ReactNative: Initializing React Xplat Bridge.
12-06 15:15:57.541 9500-9516/com.demoparentapp D/ReactNative: Initializing React Xplat Bridge before initializeBridge
12-06 15:15:57.552 9500-9519/com.demoparentapp D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0xefff9e20: ver 3 0 (tinfo 0xe9e820d0)
12-06 15:15:57.561 9500-9516/com.demoparentapp D/ReactNative: Initializing React Xplat Bridge after initializeBridge
    CatalystInstanceImpl.runJSBundle()
12-06 15:15:57.565 9500-9525/com.demoparentapp D/ReactNative: ReactInstanceManager.setupReactContext()
    CatalystInstanceImpl.initialize()
12-06 15:15:57.570 9500-9525/com.demoparentapp D/ReactNative: ReactInstanceManager.attachRootViewToInstance()
12-06 15:15:57.570 9500-9525/com.demoparentapp D/SoLoader: About to load: libyoga.so
12-06 15:15:57.571 9500-9525/com.demoparentapp D/SoLoader: libyoga.so not found on /data/data/com.demoparentapp/lib-main
    libyoga.so found on /data/app/com.demoparentapp-1/lib/x86
    Not resolving dependencies for libyoga.so
12-06 15:15:57.600 9500-9525/com.demoparentapp D/SoLoader: Loaded: libyoga.so
12-06 15:15:57.610 9500-9500/com.demoparentapp W/unknown:ReactNative: Packager connection already open, nooping.
12-06 15:15:57.627 9500-9525/com.demoparentapp D/SoLoader: init exiting
12-06 15:15:57.646 9500-9525/com.demoparentapp W/unknown:ReactNative: Tried to update non-existent root tag: 1
    Tried to update non-existent root tag: 1
12-06 15:15:57.902 9500-9525/com.demoparentapp I/WebViewFactory: Loading com.android.webview version 44.0.2403.119 (code 246011960)
12-06 15:15:57.960 9500-9524/com.demoparentapp W/ReactNativeJS: Require cycle: node_modules/react-native-firebase/dist/utils/apps.js -> node_modules/react-native-firebase/dist/modules/core/app.js -> node_modules/react-native-firebase/dist/utils/apps.js

    Require cycles are allowed, but can result in uninitialized values. Consider refactoring to remove the need for a cycle.
12-06 15:15:57.965 9500-9524/com.demoparentapp W/ReactNativeJS: Require cycle: node_modules/react-native-firebase/dist/modules/admob/index.js -> node_modules/react-native-firebase/dist/modules/admob/Interstitial.js -> node_modules/react-native-firebase/dist/modules/admob/index.js

    Require cycles are allowed, but can result in uninitialized values. Consider refactoring to remove the need for a cycle.
12-06 15:15:57.970 9500-9524/com.demoparentapp W/ReactNativeJS: Require cycle: node_modules/react-native-firebase/dist/modules/admob/index.js -> node_modules/react-native-firebase/dist/modules/admob/RewardedVideo.js -> node_modules/react-native-firebase/dist/modules/admob/index.js

    Require cycles are allowed, but can result in uninitialized values. Consider refactoring to remove the need for a cycle.
12-06 15:15:57.970 9500-9525/com.demoparentapp W/System: ClassLoader referenced unknown path: /system/app/webview/lib/x86
12-06 15:15:58.010 9500-9525/com.demoparentapp I/LibraryLoader: Time to load native libraries: 24 ms (timestamps 2122-2146)
    Expected native library version number "",actual native library version number ""
12-06 15:15:58.028 9500-9525/com.demoparentapp W/art: Attempt to remove non-JNI local reference, dumping thread
12-06 15:15:58.058 9500-9524/com.demoparentapp W/ReactNativeJS: Require cycle: node_modules/react-native-firebase/dist/modules/database/Reference.js -> node_modules/react-native-firebase/dist/utils/SyncTree.js -> node_modules/react-native-firebase/dist/modules/database/Reference.js

    Require cycles are allowed, but can result in uninitialized values. Consider refactoring to remove the need for a cycle.
12-06 15:15:58.060 9500-9524/com.demoparentapp W/ReactNativeJS: Require cycle: node_modules/react-native-firebase/dist/modules/core/firebase.js -> node_modules/react-native-firebase/dist/utils/apps.js -> node_modules/react-native-firebase/dist/modules/core/app.js -> node_modules/react-native-firebase/dist/modules/database/index.js -> node_modules/react-native-firebase/dist/modules/core/firebase.js

    Require cycles are allowed, but can result in uninitialized values. Consider refactoring to remove the need for a cycle.
12-06 15:15:58.063 9500-9524/com.demoparentapp W/ReactNativeJS: Require cycle: node_modules/react-native-firebase/dist/modules/firestore/DocumentSnapshot.js -> node_modules/react-native-firebase/dist/modules/firestore/DocumentReference.js -> node_modules/react-native-firebase/dist/modules/firestore/DocumentSnapshot.js

    Require cycles are allowed, but can result in uninitialized values. Consider refactoring to remove the need for a cycle.
    Require cycle: node_modules/react-native-firebase/dist/modules/firestore/CollectionReference.js -> node_modules/react-native-firebase/dist/modules/firestore/Query.js -> node_modules/react-native-firebase/dist/modules/firestore/QuerySnapshot.js -> node_modules/react-native-firebase/dist/modules/firestore/DocumentChange.js -> node_modules/react-native-firebase/dist/modules/firestore/DocumentSnapshot.js -> node_modules/react-native-firebase/dist/modules/firestore/DocumentReference.js -> node_modules/react-native-firebase/dist/modules/firestore/CollectionReference.js

    Require cycles are allowed, but can result in uninitialized values. Consider refactoring to remove the need for a cycle.
12-06 15:15:58.064 9500-9524/com.demoparentapp W/ReactNativeJS: Require cycle: node_modules/react-native-firebase/dist/modules/firestore/DocumentReference.js -> node_modules/react-native-firebase/dist/modules/firestore/utils/serialize.js -> node_modules/react-native-firebase/dist/modules/firestore/DocumentReference.js

    Require cycles are allowed, but can result in uninitialized values. Consider refactoring to remove the need for a cycle.
12-06 15:15:58.073 9500-9524/com.demoparentapp W/ReactNativeJS: Require cycle: node_modules/react-native-firebase/dist/modules/core/firebase.js -> node_modules/react-native-firebase/dist/utils/apps.js -> node_modules/react-native-firebase/dist/modules/core/app.js -> node_modules/react-native-firebase/dist/modules/functions/index.js -> node_modules/react-native-firebase/dist/modules/core/firebase.js

    Require cycles are allowed, but can result in uninitialized values. Consider refactoring to remove the need for a cycle.
12-06 15:15:58.082 9500-9524/com.demoparentapp W/ReactNativeJS: Require cycle: node_modules/react-native-firebase/dist/modules/storage/index.js -> node_modules/react-native-firebase/dist/modules/storage/reference.js -> node_modules/react-native-firebase/dist/modules/storage/task.js -> node_modules/react-native-firebase/dist/modules/storage/index.js

    Require cycles are allowed, but can result in uninitialized values. Consider refactoring to remove the need for a cycle.
12-06 15:15:58.086 9500-9524/com.demoparentapp E/ReactNativeJS: Java exception in 'NativeModules'

    java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Lcom/google/firebase/FirebaseApp;
12-06 15:15:58.102 9500-9524/com.demoparentapp E/ReactNativeJS: Module AppRegistry is not a registered callable module (calling runApplication)
12-06 15:15:58.158 9500-9519/com.demoparentapp D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0xefff9e20: ver 3 0 (tinfo 0xe9e820d0)
12-06 15:16:00.099 9500-9519/com.demoparentapp D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0xefff9e20: ver 3 0 (tinfo 0xe9e820d0)
12-06 15:16:00.103 9500-9519/com.demoparentapp E/Surface: getSlotFromBufferLocked: unknown buffer: 0xf413ec40
12-06 15:16:00.142 9500-9519/com.demoparentapp E/Surface: getSlotFromBufferLocked: unknown buffer: 0xf413c800
```

Here is the output from adb logcat command

```
12-06 18:51:24.991 12241 12260 E Surface : getSlotFromBufferLocked: unknown buffer: 0xee5136e0
12-06 18:51:27.311  1355  1697 W audio_hw_generic: Not supplying enough data to HAL, expected position 15554301 , only wrote 15417164
12-06 18:52:00.056  1271  1318 D hwcomposer: hw_composer sent 110 syncs in 60s
12-06 18:52:15.556  1639  1657 E BluetoothAdapter: Bluetooth binder is null
12-06 18:52:15.557  1639  1657 E KernelCpuSpeedReader: Failed to read cpu-freq
12-06 18:52:15.557  1639  1657 E KernelCpuSpeedReader: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu0/cpufreq/stats/time_in_state: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)
12-06 18:52:15.557  1639  1657 E KernelCpuSpeedReader:  at libcore.io.IoBridge.open(IoBridge.java:452)
12-06 18:52:15.557  1639  1657 E KernelCpuSpeedReader:  at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:76)
12-06 18:52:15.557  1639  1657 E KernelCpuSpeedReader:  at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:103)
12-06 18:52:15.557  1639  1657 E KernelCpuSpeedReader:  at java.io.FileReader.<init>(FileReader.java:66)
12-06 18:52:15.557  1639  1657 E KernelCpuSpeedReader:  at com.android.internal.os.KernelCpuSpeedReader.readDelta(KernelCpuSpeedReader.java:49)
12-06 18:52:15.557  1639  1657 E KernelCpuSpeedReader:  at com.android.internal.os.BatteryStatsImpl.updateCpuTimeLocked(BatteryStatsImpl.java:8002)
12-06 18:52:15.557  1639  1657 E KernelCpuSpeedReader:  at com.android.server.am.BatteryStatsService.updateExternalStats(BatteryStatsService.java:1366)
12-06 18:52:15.557  1639  1657 E KernelCpuSpeedReader:  at com.android.server.am.BatteryStatsService$BatteryStatsHandler.handleMessage(BatteryStatsService.java:125)
12-06 18:52:15.557  1639  1657 E KernelCpuSpeedReader:  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
12-06 18:52:15.557  1639  1657 E KernelCpuSpeedReader:  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
12-06 18:52:15.557  1639  1657 E KernelCpuSpeedReader:  at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:61)
12-06 18:52:15.557  1639  1657 E KernelCpuSpeedReader:  at com.android.server.ServiceThread.run(ServiceThread.java:46)
12-06 18:52:15.557  1639  1657 E KernelCpuSpeedReader: Caused by: android.system.ErrnoException: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)
12-06 18:52:15.557  1639  1657 E KernelCpuSpeedReader:  at libcore.io.Posix.open(Native Method)
12-06 18:52:15.557  1639  1657 E KernelCpuSpeedReader:  at libcore.io.BlockGuardOs.open(BlockGuardOs.java:186)
12-06 18:52:15.557  1639  1657 E KernelCpuSpeedReader:  at libcore.io.IoBridge.open(IoBridge.java:438)
12-06 18:52:15.557  1639  1657 E KernelCpuSpeedReader:  ... 11 more
12-06 18:52:15.557  1639  1657 E KernelUidCpuTimeReader: Failed to read uid_cputime
12-06 18:52:15.557  1639  1657 E KernelUidCpuTimeReader: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /proc/uid_cputime/show_uid_stat: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)
12-06 18:52:15.557  1639  1657 E KernelUidCpuTimeReader:    at libcore.io.IoBridge.open(IoBridge.java:452)
12-06 18:52:15.557  1639  1657 E KernelUidCpuTimeReader:    at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:76)
12-06 18:52:15.557  1639  1657 E KernelUidCpuTimeReader:    at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:103)
12-06 18:52:15.557  1639  1657 E KernelUidCpuTimeReader:    at java.io.FileReader.<init>(FileReader.java:66)
12-06 18:52:15.557  1639  1657 E KernelUidCpuTimeReader:    at com.android.internal.os.KernelUidCpuTimeReader.readDelta(KernelUidCpuTimeReader.java:71)
12-06 18:52:15.557  1639  1657 E KernelUidCpuTimeReader:    at com.android.internal.os.BatteryStatsImpl.updateCpuTimeLocked(BatteryStatsImpl.java:8031)
12-06 18:52:15.557  1639  1657 E KernelUidCpuTimeReader:    at com.android.server.am.BatteryStatsService.updateExternalStats(BatteryStatsService.java:1366)
12-06 18:52:15.557  1639  1657 E KernelUidCpuTimeReader:    at com.android.server.am.BatteryStatsService$BatteryStatsHandler.handleMessage(BatteryStatsService.java:125)
12-06 18:52:15.557  1639  1657 E KernelUidCpuTimeReader:    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
12-06 18:52:15.557  1639  1657 E KernelUidCpuTimeReader:    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
12-06 18:52:15.557  1639  1657 E KernelUidCpuTimeReader:    at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:61)
12-06 18:52:15.557  1639  1657 E KernelUidCpuTimeReader:    at com.android.server.ServiceThread.run(ServiceThread.java:46)
12-06 18:52:15.557  1639  1657 E KernelUidCpuTimeReader: Caused by: android.system.ErrnoException: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)
12-06 18:52:15.557  1639  1657 E KernelUidCpuTimeReader:    at libcore.io.Posix.open(Native Method)
12-06 18:52:15.557  1639  1657 E KernelUidCpuTimeReader:    at libcore.io.BlockGuardOs.open(BlockGuardOs.java:186)
12-06 18:52:15.557  1639  1657 E KernelUidCpuTimeReader:    at libcore.io.IoBridge.open(IoBridge.java:438)
12-06 18:52:15.557  1639  1657 E KernelUidCpuTimeReader:    ... 11 more
```

Comment: Have you tried to run your app with the same settings as release flavor has except debug on ?

Comment: Have you added your release SHA-1 to fcm console? Also please add logcat output if possible.

Comment: @parohy added logs to the question

Comment: @Cool7 yes i have added SHA-1 to fcm

Comment: In android studio on the right you should have a small gradle icon, open that and run a clean (its two arrows in a circle like refresh). Try to clean project from within the IDE or run appropriate commands in terminal for it.

Comment: Another thing that comes to mind, do you have `minifyEnabled true` in your release flavor? Maybe you need to define in `proguard-rules.pro` that it should not strip firebase dependencies `-dontwarn io.invertase.firebase.**`

Comment: @KireetiK there are many possible cause for this error, but majorly It seems multidex related issue or might be related to the version of google play sdk so try to update version.

Comment: @parohy i have synced gradle as you said, it says build completed successfully
that didnt help, also tried to add firebase rules to progaurd, that didnt help either.

Comment: @parohy Cool7 I have added adb logcat output, please check.

Comment: @parohy i dont have minifyEnabled.

Comment: I found solution here --> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44446523/unable-to-load-script-from-assets-index-android-bundle-on-windows/44476757#44476757