# NPM: Cannot find module 'jest-serializer' (when globally installed only)

Tags: node.js, react-native, npm

I am trying to run a react-native project on android emulator, but before I can get it to run properly, I need to run this command:

```
react-native bundle --platform android --dev false --entry-file index.js --bundle-output android/app/src/main/assets/index.android.bundle --assets-dest android/app/src/main/res
```

I got this command from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44446523/unable-to-load-script-from-assets-index-android-bundle-on-windows), as I was having the problem described there. This worked yesterday, but I created a new project this morning, and now running the command hits an error with the following stack trace:

```
Error: Cannot find module 'jest-serializer'
at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:547:15)
at Function.Module._load (module.js:474:25)
at Module.require (module.js:596:17)
at require (internal/module.js:11:18)
at _load_jestSerializer (/Users/jareddembrun/Documents/Rot3/ReactNative/MyTechLoungeReactNativeMobileApp/node_modules/jest-haste-map/build/index.js:164:52)
at HasteMap._persist (/Users/jareddembrun/Documents/Rot3/ReactNative/MyTechLoungeReactNativeMobileApp/node_modules/jest-haste-map/build/index.js:781:25)
at _buildPromise._buildFileMap.then.then.hasteMap (/Users/jareddembrun/Documents/Rot3/ReactNative/MyTechLoungeReactNativeMobileApp/node_modules/jest-haste-map/build/index.js:425:16)
at <anonymous>
at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:188:7)
```

I ran `npm install -g jest-serializer` and got back

```
+ jest-serializer@23.0.1
updated 1 package in 0.498s
```

So the module must exist on my machine. Why is react-native bundle having trouble finding it?

### Edit

Installing the `jest-serializer` locally fixed the problem, but why can't the react-native bundle script find the package if it's installed globally

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just ran into this issue also.

Looking into it I found out jest-serializer was updated yesterday to "24.0.0-alpha.7".
I had to install the previous version to get it working.

The command I ran in the project was

```
npm install jest-serializer@24.0.0-alpha.6
```

Comment: Yeah, it looks like a local install fixes it, but I'm curious why the global install doesn't work. I'll see if removing the local install and install the 24 version globally fixes it. My local install was still the 23 version and it worked. EDIT: looks like it still fails to find it if it's only installed globally.

Comment: Not sure why globally doesn't work vs locally. But I always try to keep all my packages locally because of version dependences issues.

Comment: I wouldn't want this package local because the project itself doesn't depend on it, just this setup step.