# How to navigate between components in different files and pass data react native

Tags: react-native

I am making an app for now it has 2 components. My directory structure is as follows:

```
-app
    -components
        -Dashboard
            -index.js
        -Home
            -index.js
-App.js
```

This is my `Dashboard/index.js`:

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import {Platform, StyleSheet, Text, View, Button} from 'react-native';
import { createStackNavigator, createAppContainer } from "react-navigation";
import { Header,  Icon, SearchBar, ListItem } from 'react-native-elements';


class Dashboard extends Component{
  operate() 
  {
    console.log('hello')
  }
  render() {

    return (

      <View style={styles.container}>
        <Header
          leftComponent={{ icon: 'menu', color: '#fff' }}
          centerComponent={{ text: 'App', style: { color: '#fff' } }}
          rightComponent={{ icon: 'home', color: '#fff' }}
        />
            <View>
                <Button title='back' onPress={() => this.operate()}/>
                <Button title='bookmark' onPress={() => this.operate()}/>
            </View>
            <View>
            <Text>
              This is Dashboard Screen
            </Text>
          </View>

      </View>
    );
  }
}

export default Dashboard;
```

This is my `Home/index.js`

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import {Platform, StyleSheet, Text, View, Button} from 'react-native';
import { createStackNavigator, createAppContainer } from "react-navigation";
import { Header,  Icon, SearchBar, ListItem } from 'react-native-elements';


class Home extends Component{
  operate() 
  {
    console.log('hello')
  }
  render() {

    return (

      <View style={styles.container}>
        <Header
          leftComponent={{ icon: 'menu', color: '#fff' }}
          centerComponent={{ text: 'App', style: { color: '#fff' } }}
          rightComponent={{ icon: 'home', color: '#fff' }}
        />
            <View>
              <Text>
                This is HOME
              </Text>
            </View>
            <View>
            <Button
              title="Go to Details... again"
              onPress={() => this.props.navigation.navigate('Dashboard')}
            />  
            </View>
            <View>
            {
              list.map((l, i) => (
                <ListItem 
                  key={i}
                  title={l.name}
                />
              ))
            }
          </View>

      </View>
    );
  }
}

const list = [
  {
    name: 'Amy Farha',
    avatar_url: 'https://s3.amazonaws.com/uifaces/faces/twitter/ladylexy/128.jpg',
    subtitle: 'Vice President'
  },
  {
    name: 'Chris Jackson',
    avatar_url: 'https://s3.amazonaws.com/uifaces/faces/twitter/adhamdannaway/128.jpg',
    subtitle: 'Vice Chairman'
  }
]



export default Home;
```

And this is my `App.js`

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import { createStackNavigator, createAppContainer } from "react-navigation";
import Home from './app/components/Home'
import Dashboard from './app/components/Dashboard'


const AppNavigator = createStackNavigator({
  home: {
    screen: Home
  },
  dashboard: {
    screen: Dashboard
  }
});

export default createAppContainer(AppNavigator);
```

So I am stuck here. I followed different tutorials for this. I am displaying the `list.name` on my home and when any name is pressed the user can go to `Dashboard` with rest of the details of associated with that name. But I am unable to navigate to `Dashboard` and hence I have no idea how to pass that data.
So my question is this
-How do I navigate between these component and pass the data as well?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, you must add the `onPress()` in your `ListItem` so that you will be able to press the name and pass the value as well.

```
list.map((l, i) => (
  <ListItem 
    key={i}
    title={l.name}
    onPress={()=>this._navigateToDashboard(l.name)}
  />
))
```

When the name is pressed, it will trigger the `_navigateToDashboard()` function and the `l.name` is the value that will be passed. The following code is how you're going to get the value in the function.

```
_navigateToDashboard(name){
    // navigate the dashboard screen and pass the value 
    this.props.navigation.navigate('dashboard', { any_variable_name:name })
}
```

From your dashboard, you can retrieve the passed data like this :

```
var name = this.props.navigation.state.params.any_variable_name;
```

Comment: ```The development server returned response error code: 500

URL: http://localhost:8081/index.delta?platform=android&dev=true&minify=false

Body:
{"type":"InternalError","errors":[],"message":"Metro Bundler has encountered an internal error, please check your terminal error output for more details"}
processBundleResult
```

Comment: What is your react native version?

Comment: react native version is `0.57.8`. The internal error is gone but when ever I run `react-native run-android` it stops the server and I get `Unable to load script from assets "index.android.bundle". Make sure your bundle is packaged correctly or you're running a packager server.` error.

Comment: Check this post for that error https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44446523/unable-to-load-script-from-assets-index-android-bundle-on-windows

Comment: The solution was not working I had a backup of project and ran it. And now it works. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

In `react-navigation` there is a `params` parameter that can get passed between screens.

The sending screen uses the following to navigate:

```
this.props.navigation.navigate('Details', {
    itemId: 86,
    name: 'anything you want here',
    moreDetail: {name: 'can be object'},
});
```

Then on the other screen use the following to retrieve the data:

```
const { navigation } = this.props;
const itemId = navigation.getParam('itemId', 'NO-ID-DEFAULT');
const otherParam = navigation.getParam('name', 'some default value');
const details = navigation.getParam('moreDetail', {});
```

Also reason you cannot even navigate right now is because you have:

```
onPress={() => this.props.navigation.navigate('Dashboard')}
```

while it should be:

```
onPress={() => this.props.navigation.navigate('dashboard')}
```

Since you defined as lowercase in `App.js`

Reference on how to navigate: https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/navigating.html

Reference on how to pass params: https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/params.html