# Is there a way to fix scripts cannot be loaded from index.android.bundle in the generated apk?

Tags: android, reactjs

**The application works fine on debug mode both in the simulator and real device.**

The problem occurs when I generate a signed apk and test that. 
I am fairly new to react native. I am using react native 0.57.8 .I tried upgrading my react native version to 0.59 and I still couldn't figure out the exact cause of this issue. I added the proguard rules from the official react native page.

I tried doing this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44446523/unable-to-load-script-from-assets-index-android-bundle-on-windows/44476757#44476757) but it still didn't fix my issue. I couldn't figure out where I am missing. I also tried implementing the solutions mentioned in Github repos.

Am I missing out on anything? Is there anything to be added in proguard rules and other files? Please help! I have attached the screenshot of the thrown error.

Answer (score 1):

You can try to enter the IP of your machine to your device from `Dev Settings -> Debug server host & port for device` in the debug menu available and reload the application. I hope it works.

Comment: I am facing issue in the release signed apk actually. The debug version works fine actually.