# Unable to load script from assets index.android.bundle on windows react native in vscode

Tags: react-native

I'm trying to run my first React Native project for first time on my device (Android 9.0.0).

[image]

Comment: What have you done? How did you get to this point? Have you changed any code. Please provide some more information

Comment: i well run my database project and no i can't change any code.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest ...>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<application
    ...
    android:usesCleartextTraffic="true" . <-- add this line in your manifest file
    ...>
    ...
</application>
</manifest>
```

remove android ./build folder and re-run your project

Comment: Thanks for response. does not work same error in device(8.1.0)

Comment: check this  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44446523/unable-to-load-script-from-assets-index-android-bundle-on-windows/44476757#44476757

Comment: i already try but window 8.1 not work.