# Metro bundler crashing

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-native-ios

https://github.com/inspmoore/rnw_boilerplate_nav
the web is running fine but the metro bundler is crashing every time am hitting react-native run-android,
I need help desperately kindly guide me with the reason of the crash.

Screenshot of error
[image]

[UPDATE]

As per [Unable to load script from assets index.android.bundle on windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44446523/unable-to-load-script-from-assets-index-android-bundle-on-windows), on following the instructions when I
give

```
react-native bundle --platform android --dev false --entry-file index.js --bundle-output android/app/src/main/assets/index.android.bundle --assets-dest android/app/src/main/res
```

as command am recieving

Invalid regular expression: /(.*\**fixtures**\.*|node_modules[\]react[\]dist[\].*|website\node_modules\.*|heapCapture\bundle.js|.*\**tests**\.*)$/: Unterminated character class

Comment: Did it output any errors? - if it did, could you provide these please?

Comment: hi @YannickEich have updated with the error being shown on emulator screen

Comment: Thanks, so your bundler does not log any error (which he should)?

Comment: yeah also the bundler closes before the build is completed

Comment: Yeah. But does he output any error?

Comment: no only the above error is shown for me

Comment: Whats you Desktop OS?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Unable to load script from assets index.android.bundle on windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44446523/unable-to-load-script-from-assets-index-android-bundle-on-windows)

Comment: when I give the second command which is  react-native bundle --platform android --dev false --entry-file index.js --bundle-output android/app/src/main/assets/ind
ex.android.bundle --assets-dest android/app/src/main/res,  I am getting 
Invalid regular expression: /(.*\\__fixtures__\\.*|node_modules[\\\]react[\\\]dist[\\\].*|website\\node_modules\\.*|heapCapture\\bundle\.js|.*\\__tests__\\.*)$/: Unterminated character class
as error

Comment: I would update the question with this edit, could you please check and update once?