# The release build apk is not reflecting the changes made in source code why ? -React native

Tags: react-native

I have made the changes in source code. when running it in debug mode it's working fine changes are. working there. After taking the release build changes are not reflecting in it. why ??? Android build

Answer (score 2, accepted):

react-native bundle --platform android --dev false --entry-file index.js --bundle-output android/app/src/main/assets/index.android.bundle

run this command.. may be it's sounds weird but it's work for me

reference : https://stackoverflow.com/a/60015205/6654562

Answer (score 0):

Before Trying to build APK run `gradlew clean` and clean the gradle folder this will remove all the previous builds. Then try to build the release APK

Answer (score 0):

You need to `build->clean` then `build->rebuild project` in android studio