# React Native android bundle overrides

Tags: javascript, java, android, reactjs, react-native

I have android project that I'm trying to import some react native code to. But thing is I only want it to have the 'index.android.bundle' file. Now, when I start my metro bundler from the dev react native folder, it fetches the files fine, hermes loads and my code works. But when I try to assemble release apk, the local react native overrides the 'index.android.bundle' file and opening an empty 'mock' screen. I tried lot of stuff, but I suppose it's an issue somewhere in my setup, since it supposed to work.

If issue wasn't clear - I compile my project with './gradlew assembleRelease' command. If the 'index.android.bundle' file was changed somehow or is missing, it will re-build that file using the local metro config, which is quite empty, and not use the bundle I copied earlier to assets folder from another project(which is the right one I want to use).

Thx in advance.

I tried to assemble release version when the metro bundler runs in correct folder, tried to copy correct bundle into assets of the target project. Doesn't matter what I do, any minor change to the bundle file will re-create it, override and open empty activity instead of my app.

Comment: Try setting `bundleInRelease: false` and removing/commenting line `bundleReleaseJsAndAssets.dependsOn('bundleInRelease')`  from file `android/app/build.gradle`.

Comment: That didn't work, tried also with setting 
react {
    debuggableVariants = ["debug", "release"]
}

Answer (score 1):

Try this link :
[Unable to load script from assets index.android.bundle on windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44446523/unable-to-load-script-from-assets-index-android-bundle-on-windows)

The following information relates to Android bundle overrides for React Native :

1. The React Native development process makes use of the index.android.bundle file. It has the JavaScript code for your app that has been packed and compiled.
   The index.android.bundle file will be rebuilt using the local metro config if it changes or missing.
2. One can override whether the bundle is minified by using the -minify option. If dev is true, then this defaults to false; otherwise, it defaults to true.
3. If you need to modify the way the drawable resources and/or JavaScript bundle are packed, you can see how to alter android/app/build.gradle to reflect these modifications.
4. By utilising command-line options, you can override the default.