# UWP app sideload on hockeyapp error: Unable to download JS Bundle

Tags: react-native, uwp, hockeyapp

I've built UWP in react-native. When I run it on locale with react-native run-windows command app works fine. Now I've deployed it on Hockeyapp. When I download it on some other system and run there it throws error **Unable to download JS Bundle** Please check screenshot for more. Can anyone tell where and what I'm missing?

[image: Error while running on testing machine]

**Windows folder structure:**

[image: Windows folder structure]

Comment: @NicoZhu-MSFT why and which URL test machine need to access on developer machine?

Comment: Have you checked this [case](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32572399/react-native-android-failed-to-load-js-bundle)?

Comment: @NicoZhu-MSFT For windows I have this folder structure(Check image in question) can you please tell how to implement the solution in this as suggested in above-attached answer by you, it's for android.