# React-Native 0.57: 'Can't find variable: require' with metro-react-native-babel-preset

Tags: reactjs, react-native, babeljs, babel-polyfill

I started a multiplatform project with code sharing between react-native and react-js.
So I have a webpack setup for browser/Electron, and a react-native 0.57 setup for Android/iOS.
The problem I'm having right now is the following:
[Can't find variable: require](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YK4vD.png)

It might be a very bald question, but do I need anything else? I read, that React-native should support require by itself, but couldn't find anything related to this setup yet.

`.babelrc
{"presets": ["module:metro-react-native-babel-preset"]}`

I'm also using @babel/polyfill and @babel/runtime on browser side, but I wonder if they would interfere.

Comment: Check this thread they have a solution https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/21048. Check m-vbd babel config and takion solution their comments should help fix the issue

Answer (score 6):

Got the solution, my .babelrc was okay, but the packager cached the very first wrong one so I had to start the packager as:
`react-native start --reset-cache`

Answer (score 2):

After looking at below github issue it looks like the issue is caused by corejs option @babel/plugin-transform-runtime, So replace it by @babel/polyfil

https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/21048

.babelrc config for ref

```
  {
  "presets": [
      "module:metro-react-native-babel-preset",
  ],
  "plugins": [
      "react-require",
   [
        "module-resolver",
     {
        "root": [
          "./src",
          "./assets"
        ],
        "alias": {
           "app": "./src",
          "assets": "./assets"
         }
      }
    ],
    [
        "babel-plugin-require-context-polyfill",
   {
    "alias": {
      "app": "./src"
    }
  }
   ],

     "@babel/plugin-proposal-export-default-from",
     "@babel/plugin-proposal-export-namespace-from",

    "@babel/plugin-transform-flow-strip-types",
   [
     "@babel/plugin-proposal-decorators",
  {
    "legacy": true
  }
    ],
     [
      "@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties",
      {
    "loose": false
      }
     ],

      [
       "@babel/plugin-transform-runtime",
       {

       }
     ],

   ],
     "sourceMaps": true
 }
```

Install   Babel polyfill 7  "@babel/polyfill": "^7.0.0"

And import that in App component

```
  import '@babel/polyfill'
```

Comment: @babel/polyfill is already installed and imported, already tried a bunch of plugins, but none of them helped.
There are a lot of plugins in this solution that I'm not sure I would need. Which one is the key or how do they chain up to solve the case?

Comment: I experienced similar issues by adding `@babel/preset-env`, `@babel/preset-react` and `@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties`

Answer (score 1):

It seems that `react-native start --reset-cache` works.