# Failed to start application in for latest React-native

Tags: react-native

I created a new application:

```
$ react-native init myapp
```

Then tried to start it in ios:

```
$ react-native run-ios --port=9999
```

Got the following error message:

> No bundle URL present

My React-native version is 0.60.3. But I have no problem to run my app for android by:

```
$ react-native run-android --port=9999
```

And I also have no problem to run myapp in previous react-native version 0.59.9.

Any idea?

Comment: How does your AppDelegate.m look like?

Comment: My metro builder wan't starting during the build process. I opened up a new terminal window within the project and ran `react-native start` to kick start the metro bundler JS server.

Comment: @JRK Tried this a few times already. I guess it's a bug in 0.60.3 because everything is fine in 0.59.9.

Comment: I found the problem. In 0.60.3:
***export RCT_METRO_PORT="${RCT_METRO_PORT:=9999}***
in Start Packager. But in 0.59.9, this does not exists.

Comment: @Bagusflyer - great, I'll try that also. I'm assuming you hadn't gone to 0.60 - which had the No implementation Java bug! RN is never ending!

Comment: the problem for me was that i didn't correctly configure my environment in android studio, i found the answer to that here
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38835931/react-native-adb-reverse-enoent