# Not able to run android emulator (android-studio) with react-native

Tags: android, react-native, android-studio, android-emulator, adb

I am just starting to create a new react-native project and I followed the steps exactly as mentioned in [setting-up environment for react-native](https://reactnative.dev/docs/environment-setup).

My development OS: Mac; My target OS: Android

I created a local.properties file in my project/android directory which mentions sdk path. I have the android emulator up and running, then I do `yarn react-native start`, and in another terminal window, `yarn react-native run:android` but I get the following error:

```
BUILD SUCCESSFUL in 28s
27 actionable tasks: 27 executed
info Connecting to the development server...
warn Failed to connect to development server using "adb reverse": spawnSync adb ENOENT
info Starting the app...
error Failed to start the app. Run CLI with --verbose flag for more details.
Error: spawnSync adb ENOENT
    at Object.spawnSync (internal/child_process.js:1066:20)
error Command failed with exit code 1.
```

`yarn react-native run:ios` command runs perfectly alright.

Could anyone help with this please? I have tried the various different suggestions mentioned in this [stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38835931/react-native-adb-reverse-enoent) but no luck.

Comment: can you launch emulator from other ways? for example from android studio itself?

Comment: @AADProgramming yes I'm able to launch it directly from Android studio

Comment: I'm getting the same error. can you fix it?

Comment: @fmchan I was able to fix it by verifying that my path was set up correctly in bash profile. In my case, the paths were not being persisted because I wasn't adding them correctly. Ran the emulator from android studio, once it was up, the command was able to load my app. Hope this helps.
Sorry for the late reply.