# React-Native: Error: spawnSync adb ENOENT at Object.spawnSync

Tags: android, react-native

When I run `react-native run-android` I keep getting the following error. I tried adding `export ANDROID_SDK=/Users/<your_computer_name>/Library/Android/sdk export PATH=/Users/<your_computer_name>/Library/Android/sdk/platform-tools:$PATH` to my ~/.zshrc file but haven't had any luck. Thanks in advance!

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [React Native adb reverse ENOENT](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38835931/react-native-adb-reverse-enoent)

Comment: No. I tried the solution in that answer (adding the info to my ./zshrc file), but the issue still occurs. In addition, my build is successful but the app isn't started. This indicates that it is a different issue than the one in that question.

Comment: Did anybody find the solution for this issue?

Answer (score 1):

I ran `adb reverse tcp:8081 tcp:8081` and then restarted the server, and re-ran the `react-native run-android` command and it worked.