# React Native Error : error Failed to start the app. Error: spawnSync adb ENOENT

Tags: android, react-native, android-studio

I faced this error.

warn Failed to connect to development server using "adb reverse": spawnSync adb ENOENT
info Starting the app...
error Failed to start the app.
Error: spawnSync adb ENOENT

```bash
error Failed to start the app. Error: spawnSync adb ENOENT
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```bash
brew install --cask android-platform-tools
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to update ANDROID_HOME env and then compile your changes with the following command running on terminal

```
source ~/.bash_profile
```

Kindly follow this link
[React Native adb reverse ENOENT](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38835931/react-native-adb-reverse-enoent)