# React-native-beacons-android: getting error - CycledLeScanner: No Bluetooth adapter. beaconService cannot scan

Tags: android, react-native

My manifest file contains the following:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW"/>
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH"/>
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADMIN"/>
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED"/>

<!-- Declaration that this app is usable on phones with Bluetooth Low Energy. -->
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.bluetooth_le" android:required="true"/>
```

I am trying to run the native app on android and while i run the app i get this error.

```
RN version - 0.31
 Running on android emulator version 6 marshmallow.
```

Comment: Bluetooth is not supported on Android emulators [https://developer.android.com/studio/run/emulator.html](https://developer.android.com/studio/run/emulator.html)

Comment: Thanks Xeijp. While trying to run the app on my samsung phone- (4.3), I am getting the error as "Could not get BatchedBridge, make sure your bundle is packaged correctly". Any suggestions.

Comment: Got solved - check link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31525431/getting-error-closed-twice-on-adb-reverse